# java web app profiler like this

Tags: java, profiler, mvc-mini-profiler

Read an article on
http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/

Any open-source profiler available like this for java web apps?

Anyone started to port this one to Java environment?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is one java "mini profiler" project inspired by `mvc-mini-profiler` for the Google App Engine Java runtime 
([`gae-java-mini-profiler`](https://github.com/jriecken/gae-java-mini-profiler)).

You can see a [demo](http://gae-java-mini-profiler.appspot.com/).

Comment: I recommend this mini profiler too. It's easy to use. We've used this to make the same feature they use on SO. We used Spring AOP and annotations to instrument crucial methods.

Answer (score 1):

BTrace is a good agent that can be used to get the profiling information out of your JVM (anything from memory usage, thread usage, to method execution times and invocation counts). I have written an application (EurekaJ) that integrated with BTrace to let you visualize and create thresholds based on the data gathered by BTrace.

I have never used MVC Mini Profiler, but BTrace + EurekaJ is indeed a fully open-source solution. Im not aware of any other open-sourced profilers for the Java Platform, but something may exist.

BTrace: http://kenai.com/projects/btrace
EurekaJ: http://eurekaj.haagen.name

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a port for this project.

You can essentially use JUnit and [JunitPerf](http://www.clarkware.com/software/JUnitPerf.html) to   measure the performance and scalability of functionality.  It doesn't look as as easy to do, but it should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

[java-mini-profiler](https://github.com/alvins82/java-mini-profiler-core)

This is one I wrote which takes from gae-java-mini-profiler but works for non-gae applications. It also some extra features which can be optionally enabled such as profiling annotation and sql profiling.