# Is there something similar to mini-mvc-profiler for Java?

Tags: java, performance, web-applications, profiler

Like the title said:

**Is there something similar to the [mini-mvc-profiler](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/) for Java?**

I'm looking for something that can be used in a [Struts](http://struts.apache.org/) or [Spring MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mvc.html) application and that shows a quick performance overview on every page in our DEV environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[java-mini-profiler](https://github.com/alvins82/java-mini-profiler-core)

This is one I wrote which takes from gae-java-mini-profiler but works for non-gae applications. It also some extra features which can be optionally enabled such as profiling annotation and sql profiling.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest can be [Java Interactive profiler](http://jiprof.sourceforge.net/)

Another interesting and effective one is [glassbox](http://glassbox.sourceforge.net/glassbox/Home.html)

It depends on case to case basis. Sometimes even using a simple performance logging library like [per4j](http://perf4j.codehaus.org/devguide.html) works.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend:  [gae-java-mini-profiler](https://github.com/jriecken/gae-java-mini-profiler)

It has been posted here earlier:
[Is there something similar to mini-mvc-profiler for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6441069/142824)