# Finding bottlenecks in a Java EE application

Tags: performance, web-applications, jakarta-ee

We have developed a Java EE application and it will be in production soon.
Before that I'm trying to find bottlenecks inside this application.

I found this site:
http://www.slideshare.net/batterywalam/performance-bottleneck-identification

Please refer to the screen shot there.

Could anyone please tell me what `Diagnostic tools` are and what the difference is between a diagnostic tool and a profiler? Do we need to use both of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually a diagnostic tool is used to troubleshoot a specific problem once it has been identified, or to give you a wide range of stats about the overall performance of your code.

A profiler, on the other hand, is used to show what you're looking for specifically (bottlenecks).  It shows how long each call in your application is taking, so that you can easily identify areas that will be long running or should be re-examined for purposes of optimization.

Once you've determined where your trouble spots are using the profiler, you can use diagnostic tools to get more insight/ideas about why the code is slow and possibly to diagnose what the root cause of that problem is (long SQL calls, slow processing of large results sets, etc).

Comment: It was great explanation , i am think of Jprobe for profiling , but worried of its learning curve , any ideas of what would be best , anyways our management will not buy the license but use it until the trail period only .

Comment: Check out the ones listed over here. I've had a lot of use out of the Java Interactive Profiler, myself. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503072/is-there-something-similar-to-mini-mvc-profiler-for-java